# Services bundle not properly getting deployed over Jenkins

Tags: service, jenkins, adobe, bundle, aem

> I've faced some mystical problem over here. I deploy my Adobe CQ
>   project over Jenkins and my services package not getting deployed at
>   all. I mean, they are absent in install folder in my CRXDE. When I am
>   trying to do the same stuff on localhost with maven manually - it's
>   working like charm. For some reason, i've noticed in logs, that
>   services bundle installed, started, then stopped and uninstalled, but
>   there are no any errors or something. What reason can cause this
>   issue? I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

---

**Guys, I have found the answer: there was empty "/install" folder in my project structure so when i deploy my packages, 'View' package with empty '/install' folder in it simply rewrites just added 'Services' and 'Taglib' jars from '/install' folder in crxde.**

Answer (score 1):

If you delete jar from `../install/` JCR folder, it will be uninstalled from the OSGi as well. I think it may be an issue with the CRX package filters. If you install a few packages, one after another, and they are sharing same paths, then the latter package will delete resources installed by the former one.